# How the configuration can be saved from the application

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, appsettings

Dependency injection from the box (Microsoft) has good stuffs, precisely IConfiguration interface, which allows to get stored configuration data using different providers and then to bind it with different classes using Options patterns. It's a really good stuff, but IConfiguration interface has only mechanism to read data and does not have to save data. From the other hand, usually, applications have possibility to change their configuration and to store it some where. Do you have any idea how I can implement this option?

Initially, I've stored some configuration data into the appsettings.json file and when I configure the DI container I get these data and bind their with particular class.

```csharp
public static IHostBuilder ConfigureHost(this IHostBuilder builder)
        {
            _ = builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
              {
                  _ = config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                          .AddJsonFile("appsettings12.json")
                          .Build();
              });

            _ = builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                  services.Configure<OptionsModel>(context.Configuration.GetSection("Options"))
                      .AddSingleton<IOptionsService, OptionsService>()
                      .AddSingleton<MainWindowModelView>()
                      .AddSingleton<MainWindow>()
            );

            return builder;
        }
```

This code works fine, but I can't find is there any mechanism in the box to store the changed configuration data back. There is a form to change these configuration data and I want to save their to the file. Could anyone to suggest me how I can save it?

Comment: Configuration values are intended to be input values to the application. If you have a situation where certain values change in runtime, then it might be a value that relates to the domain rather then a setting on the application. If thats the case I would store it in the db instead

Comment: @MarcusHöglund, This is small program to manage indexes of DB. It is not supposed to store anything in the DB. So, initial settings shall be store in the config file. Then, if user change something, it shall be stored. As I understand, the standard features from Microsoft does not provide such option. I mean DI container from Microsoft. It seems that I shall it by myself.

Comment: Moreover, the AddJsonFile method has an optional parameter "reloadOnChange". If we set it to true, it means that class using relevant option pattern will be updated when the file is changed. It's obvious that anyone can change this file and an application can be one of them from my point of view.